# For friendly URL getting 404 error on Lucee

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, friendly-url, lucee, missing-template

[image: here is the 404 error screen]

I have custom friendly URLs as mentioned in above image, I did configure in IIS > 404 Error> Added path/URL if 404 to which executes if page not found, and also added same in Lucee administration settings > 404 (missing template)

Can you please help if any configuration is missed from IIS

Comment: You can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Do you want to pass that requests to Lucee?

Comment: Yes. But not sure what are the settings in IIS or in Lucee to be update

Comment: That depends very much on how your web app needs to receive the URL. A very common way is to use IIS UrlRewrite in IIS and use rules like used by common cfml Frameworks. As an example see https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/routing/requirements/rewrite-rules But as I said, your Web App needs to be able to identify those passed requests to be able to make them work.

Comment: This has been resolved.

Missing host entries on my servers